# Check if a value exists in a postgresql database?

Tags: javascript, database, postgresql

My program is as follows. Basically, it adds an attendee and a workshop to a database, but first I need to check if both the attendee and workshop are already in the database, together. I can't figure out how to properly do this. I found one statement select exists, but I'm not sure if I'm implementing it correctly. Is there anyway to return a true or false statement if the values are already in the database?

```
66 app.post("/api", async (req,res) => {
 67         const attendee = req.body.attendee;
 68         const workshop = req.body.workshop;
 69 
 70 
 71         try {
 72 
 73                 const test = 'SELECT EXISTS (SELECT true FROM people WHERE attendee=$1'; // is this right?
 74                 
 75                 const template = "INSERT INTO people (attendee,workshop) VALUES ($1,$2)";
 76                 const responce = await pool.query(template, [
 77                         attendee,
 78                         workshop
 79                 ]);     
 80                 res.json({results:{attendee: attendee, workshop: workshop } });
 81         } catch (err) {
 82                 // if either argument is missing
 83                 res.json({ error:'parameters not given'});
 84         }       
 85 });
```

Comment: Really `select * from people where attendee=$1` is enough, because you'll get zero rows back if nothing in the table satisfies the predicate.

Comment: Or `select count(*) ...` to get zero or non-zero

Comment: You are missing a closing parenthesis on the EXISTS statement.

Comment: You re never running that query?!

Comment: Notice that your table should have foreign key references to the workshops table and to the attendees table, so you could just try inserting and it would fail if attendee and workshop don't exist.

Comment: your variable, "test" is just a string of SQL... it doesn't appear to be ran. You'll need to run it and write a conditional (if, while, etc) based on the result.